Trouble deploying to Digital Ocean k8
I am currently trying to deploy a microservice to a Digital Ocean k8 cluster using Github actions. It is a C# microservice project (aggregator - services).
I have created a workflow but am getting issues building the image/s. I assumed I need to build images for all Dockerfiles in the solution ie.
    - name: Build container image - Aggregator
      run: docker build -t registry.digitalocean.com/api1:$(echo $GITHUB_SHA | head -c7) -f Project/Api1/Dockerfile .
    
    - name: Build container image - Aggregator
      run: docker build -t registry.digitalocean.com/api2:$(echo $GITHUB_SHA | head -c7) -f Project/Api2/Dockerfile .

   ...etc.
     

I get the following when the action is run:
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 154f1920-6824-4aef-6297-2479404a90ff::zjkFYuxjks4ecryvjrilk0qsr: "/Api1.csproj": not found

Any ideas on how to resolve this?
I have also tried to deploy from local machine but all I have for the apis deployed is the status "ImagePullBackOff"
EDIT:
Here is an example Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Api1.csproj", "Api1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./Api1/./Api1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Api1"
RUN dotnet build "./Api1.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./Api1.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api1.dll"]


you need copy Api1.csproj to your image

This question might be better suited for DevOps.

@Mate can you elaborate?

@Mate added the Dockerfile in question

you  COPY ["Api1.csproj", "Api1/"]   then RUN... "./Api1/./Api1.csproj" and then.. WORKDIR "/src/Api1" . Why ?  ,  In any case, try WORKDIR /src/Api1 without quotes
